# how to return 2 values of different type from a java function : for dummies only

Tags: java, types, return-value

i searched this topic and found answers, but being a java dummy, i don't really understand it all and therefor i tried to execute the best answer i found into a little example :

```
package return2valuesofdifftype;
public class Return2ValuesOfDiffType {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("started");
        String strHere = "nothing happened";
        int iHere = -5;
        Method myM = new Method();
        ReturningValues myRV = new ReturningValues(strHere, iHere);
        myRV = myM.method(5, 10);   //should return a RV holding the string "correct" and the integer 1

    //so far so good (i hope), but how to get this string and integer out of RV ???

    System.out.println("string = "+strHere+" ,en i = "+iHere);
    }
}

package return2valuesofdifftype;
public final class ReturningValues {
    private final String value;
    private final int index;

    public ReturningValues(String value, int index) {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }   
}

package return2valuesofdifftype;
public class Method {
    public ReturningValues method(int five, int ten) {
        String str="";
        int i=-1;
        if(five==5){str="correct";}
        else{str="wrong";}
        if(ten==10){i=1;}
        else{i=0;}
        ReturningValues rv = new ReturningValues(str, i);
        return rv;
    } 
}
```

My Question : how to get this integer and string out of RV ?
Thanks a lot ! 
dad

Comment: Either change the visibility of the relevant fields from `private` to `public` or create *getters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding getter methods is one way...

```
public final class ReturningValues 
{
    private final String value;
    private final int index;

    public ReturningValues( String value, int index ) 
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }   

    public String getString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public String getInteger()
    {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to change the visibility of the attributes to public.

```
public final class ReturningValues 
{
    public final String value;
    public final int index;

    public ReturningValues( String value, int index ) 
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide getters for the two variables in your ReturningValues implementation like this:

```
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}
```

Then you can call myRV.getValue(); or myRV.getIndex();